# How can I add values to NSArray of different class A from Class B

Tags: objective-c

I have my .m file where I need to update NSArray of class B, where I should be able to the values from that array.

I am trying this in Class A

```
// TabHeaderViewModel.h


typedef enum {
  UsePassHeaderType,
  ManageCardType
}TabHeaderType;
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@interface TabHeaderViewModel : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) TabHeaderType headerType;
- (instancetype)initWithHeaderType:(TabHeaderType)headerType;
- (NSArray *)dataSourceForHeaderModel;
@end
```

And now I want to access datatSourceForHeaderModel from class B in its .m file

```
TabHeaderViewModel *headerVM = [[TabHeaderViewModel alloc]initWithHeaderType:ManageCardType];
    headerVM.dataSourceForHeaderModel = self.dataSourceForHeader; 
    // getting error  - No setter method 'setDataSourceForHeaderModel:' for assignment to property
```

Comment: You’re calling a setter method but you’ve only added a getter method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either code in interface

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *dataSourceForHeaderModel;
```

or

```
-(void)setDataSourceForHeaderModel:(NSArray*)datasource;
```

also do your implementation when you define a method if there is processing.
But its easier to go with the *property* solution.